# How to hold contents and show skeleton loader first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

My blog when loaded using a poor connection is very uncomfortable to look at and heavy.  Sometimes only the main content is visible without the sidebar and footer for a few moments. How to hold contents and show skeleton loader first?

Comment: Following some of the tips [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Author_fast-loading_HTML_pages) may help.

Answer (score 0):

## Hello

Do you want to make a documentation ? to show html markup like this right [image]
Please visit this link [demo](https://www.taniarascia.com/basic-html5-file/)
or more help [Help Link](https://www.facebook.com/mrana.2779)

Comment: No sir, it's just skeleton of my blog. I'm looking for skeleton loader for my blog. Sorry maybe my question is a bit confusing, I just realized it now.